# GROUP BY ignore groups containing NULL value and fetch recent record by date from each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a `user_details` table as below.

```
id  user_id start_date  end_date

1   55      5-1-2017    NULL
2   55      3-1-2017    4-30-2017
3   66      1-1-2018    1-31-2018
4   66      2-1-2018    4-12-2018
5   77      11-1-2016   11-30-2016
6   77      12-1-2016   NULL
7   99      8-1-2016    1-31-2017
8   99      7-1-2016    7-31-2016
```

I have to fetch the latest record by `start_date` for each user but fetch only those users having `end_date` set for all records of that user.

The output should be as below:

```
id  user_id start_date  end_date

4   66      2-1-2018    4-12-2018
7   99      8-1-2016    1-31-2017
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: *for each user but fetch only those users having end_date set* this condition applies to any row of that user or just to the latest row?

Comment: I have to fetch only those users having end_date set for all records of that user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` and an `ORDER BY` clause to get the row with the latest `start_date` per group.
Then eliminate the results with `end_date IS NULL`.

```
SELECT id, user_id, start_date, end_date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
             id, user_id, start_date, end_date
      FROM user_detail
      ORDER BY user_id, start_date DESC, end_date, id) AS q
WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to aggregate by `user_id`, and then identify which users have an `end_date` from the latest record which is not `NULL`.  We use a CTE to find the max `start_date` value for each user.  In the `HAVING` clause we assert that when the `start_date` is the latest starting date, the `end_date` is also not `NULL`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, user_id, start_date, end_date,
        MAX(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) max_start_date
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    user_id,
    MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
    MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    user_id
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN start_date = max_start_date AND
                    end_date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select u.*
from user_details u
where not exists (
  select 1 from user_details
  where user_id = u.user_id and (start_date > u.start_date or end_date is null)
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jVo7ZpovyoctJdYUHKiDm/2).
Results:

```
| id  | user_id | start_date | end_date  |
| --- | ------- | ---------- | --------- |
| 4   | 66      | 2018-02-01 | 2018-04-12|
| 7   | 99      | 2016-08-01 | 2017-01-31|
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT ON` with the right index might be the most efficient method.  But that index is quite specific:  `(user_id, start_date DESC, end_date, id)`.  The following should have similar performance but with a simpler index:

```
select ud.*
from user_details ud
where ud.id = (select ud2.id
               from user_details ud2
               where ud2.user_id = ud.user_id
               order by ud2.start_date desc
               limit 1
              ) and
       ud.end_date is not null;
```

For this, you want an index on `user_details(user_id, start_date desc, id)`.